# woo commerce - how to show custom fields on published page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have set 2 custom fields on the wordpress / woocommerce product page called "imballo" and "sottoimballo" with their values. How do I display these on the published page?

Thanks!

Comment: The same way you'd display any other post meta...[get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to display the custom fields in the WooCommerce Single Product Page template,

You could do it in two ways,

1. Add a code in an existing hook of the Product Single page. Check hooks [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/#section-2)
2. Modify the template by overriding it in your WordPress theme. Read [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

And in the place where you want to display do the following,

```
<?php
     //Please add your HTML structure as needed.
     echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'imballo');
     echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'sottoimballo');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess best solution is hooks but don't understand well how to do this...could you please help me again?

Comment: You are welcome. Go and search the best hook in the Product Single Page of WooCommerce where you want to display your custom values. and then write this code either in a plugin or your theme's function.php
add_action("hook_name", "show_custom_data"); function show_function_data(){ //echo the meta fields }

Comment: I tried:

add_action("woocommerce_single_product_summary", "show_custom_data"); function show_custom_data(){ 
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'imballo');
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'sottoimballo'); }


But it returns on the page the following: ArrayArray